# error: cannot find symbol variable main

Tags: android, android-studio, program-entry-point

I have tried to make a project with help of this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm I have created all the necessary files, but I get the following error.

[image: Cannot resolve symbol 'main']

I have tried to solve this by importing android.R, cleaning/rebuilding project, syncing project with gradle files. I have also checked XML files, these are without error.

Comment: Sorry, but I have not had enough time after this post. I always sign the correct answers, sorry again! And thanks a lot for the solution!

Comment: I have deleted the comment as after going through it again, I found it's tone to be a bit harsh, though that wasn't my intention.. Anyways, the intent was to only make you aware about how to keep contributors motivated [ you are one of them too :) ].. Happy contributing bro.. Cya around!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tutorial you are referring to has missed to include the menu file 'main' under the menu folder.. Include main.xml in your menu folder (if it doesn't exist, create one under resources directory).

Comment: In case you are not sure about the layout of the menu xml, Check any tutorial available online regarding how to create the menu layout..

Answer (score 0):

Further to above, the tutorial in question does have a menu xml, in the menu folder under the res folder; however, it is called menu_main.xml. You just need to change the reference:

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
```

to

```
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
```

Worked for me atleast :P
Nige